# Why are so many Subject objects in RX?

Tags: rxjs, behaviorsubject

Could you clarify the following things — why are

1. Subject
2. BehaviourSubject
3. ReplaySubject

exist all together?

When only Subject with the buffer parameter would be enough? 
After all, only this (emit last amount) they differ.

It might be: (param is Buffer size)

- Subject(0) = normal Subject();
- Subject(1) = BehaviourSubject();
- Subject(5) = ReplaySubject(5);

What reasons?

Comment: You can read it in the docs https://rxjs.dev/api?query=subject

Comment: I read docs. I read articles. Is question clear not enough? Docs and articles just explain these things as itself, but don't answer the question.

Comment: Each one does a different thing as it's described in docs. You can't interchange them as they have different functionality.

Comment: I beg pardon, but different things are RxJS and MS SQL. But subjects (RX) are inherited from one parent and share same functionality. Can you show a reason - why I can not interchange them?

Comment: It's already described here. Just read the description at the top. It tells you what's the difference https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/ReplaySubject  https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Subject

Comment: man, I understand the difference. I talk about reasons - why architects of RX create three different objects instead of creating one with some params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)
Subject doesn't even hold values.
All the values emitted before subscribing will not be seen by subscribers.

2)
BehaviorSubject holds the last value and must hold a value.
Subscribers will always get the last emitted value.

3) 
ReplaySubject holds x values, but doesn't have to.
Subscribers will get last x values if they were emitted before. Otherwise they will get 0 - x values.

They are different and can not be changed between themselves without losing functionality.

Comment: I don't get it. All of them have one key point - emit items. 
Have I really care of what kind (type) of 'subject' emit item that I get?  
All that you describe up there - can be solve with constructor params. 

I wonder, is it really really necessary to have precisely different types of 'subjects' instead of solving it through constructors? 

But I got your main thought.

Comment: I mean, you could have a few constructor options for `AnySubject` let's call it. `constructor(holdValues: boolean, valuesToHold: number, initialValue: T | T[])` etc. But that would just get more and more complicated. And this way is much easier for developers to reason about. Doesn't help that TypeScript doesn't have proper contructor overloading.